# i want to update table multiple row using IN statement

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE domain_information
SET company_name = 'aaa'
where id in (select id from domain_information where company_name = 'bbb')
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition can be simplified like

```
UPDATE domain_information
SET company_name = 'aaa'
WHERE company_name = 'bbb';
```

Comment: As long as no 'bbb' id is null.

Comment: @jarlh, Yes, that's a implicit assumption that the id OP referring to in post is primary key of the table.